# How to use Jquery to get the string value of current cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used this code to create bunch of alphabet character from a - z

```
var textAppend = $("<div>").html(textPre); // for loop keep changing textPre
$(".name-select-header").append(textAppend);
```

And after that I want to have a mouseover function implemented,
inside the function I want it to be able to get the value of current cursor at.

For example,
If my mouse is on character "a", I want to display "apple" , "america" in a div section.
if it is on "b", "banana" and "Benz" are displayed in that div section.

So what should I do to make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted doesn't give me enough information, but if I were to do it, I would have different `span` elements with a letter in each one, put them all under one class (`letter` for example), and use the jQuery `mouseover()` handler to call a function that displays the words in your desired div.

Here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/rNmUp/3/